# How do I apply a function to one column split by each factor in another column of a data frame using ddply?

Tags: r, dataframe, split, plyr

M data looks like this:

Label: 1 1 1 2 3 2 5 5 5 2 2 3 3 5 6 7 8...
Numbers: 132 123 838 29 1 23 0 283 238 2 123 2 ...

Both columns are numerics and I want to calculate the quantiles of Numbers for each of the factors in Label.

```
#the function I want to use to calc the quantiles
qfn <- function(x) quantile(x, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.2), na.rm = TRUE)

#Using the by function
results <- by(data$Numbers, data$Label, qfn)
```

I get the right results but it's a "by" class instead of a data frame.

```
Label: 1  
0%      20%     40%     60%     80%     100%   
1.2     3.5     7.8     9.10    30.1    105.3

Label: 2  
0%      20%     40%     60%     80%     100%   
1.9     2.5     5.8     8.10    23.1    99.3

...
```

**How do I use ddply to get these same results but in a data frame?**

When I use something like:

```
results <- ddply(data, "Label", qfn)
```

I get the correct groupings by the factors of Label but the function is applied to the wrong column in my case--it's also applied to the values of Label when I want the function applied to Numbers instead.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This got me the results I wanted but not using ddply

```
result <- do.call(rbind, with(data, {tapply(data$Numbers, data$Label, qfn)}))
```